# Cannot get activemq Docker image to run as service in portainer

Tags: java, docker, yaml, activemq-classic, portainer

I have an ActiveMQ Docker image stored in a local Nexus repository.

I am attempting to deploy ActiveMQ from this image as a service on a Portainer instance using the following stack.yml: -

```
version: "3"
networks:
  jon:
services:          
  activemq:
    image: nexus:21111/activemq:latest
    ports:
      - "15100:61616"
    volumes:
      - /jon/test/activemq/data:/data/activemq
      - /jon/test/activemq/conf:/opt/activemq/conf
      - /jon/test/activemq/log:/var/log/activemq
    networks:
      - jon
    environment:
      ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_LOGIN: xxxxx
      ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD: xxxxx
      PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
      ACTIVEMQ_CONFIG_DIR: /opt/activemq/conf
      ACTIVEMQ_DATA_DIR: /data/activemq
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.affinity == ${NODE}
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

Prior to deploying this stack.yml, I created the three host volumes specified in the volumes section. I set full read write permissions on these directories for all users.

When I attempted to deploy the yml file in Portainer, the image is retrieved and a Container starts with a status of "Running". However, when I examine the logs, I see the following: -

```
2019-03-15 15:08:50,450 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-03-15 15:08:50,450 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/activemq.conf" during parsing
2019-03-15 15:08:50,450 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/cron.conf" during parsing
2019-03-15 15:08:50,469 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-03-15 15:08:50,469 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-03-15 15:08:50,470 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2019-03-15 15:08:51,473 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 16
2019-03-15 15:08:51,477 INFO spawned: 'activemq' with pid 17
2019-03-15 15:08:52,219 INFO exited: activemq (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-03-15 15:08:53,221 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-03-15 15:08:53,222 INFO spawned: 'activemq' with pid 87
2019-03-15 15:08:53,980 INFO exited: activemq (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-03-15 15:08:55,983 INFO spawned: 'activemq' with pid 158
2019-03-15 15:08:56,721 INFO exited: activemq (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-03-15 15:08:59,726 INFO spawned: 'activemq' with pid 229
2019-03-15 15:09:00,443 INFO exited: activemq (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-03-15 15:09:01,445 INFO gave up: activemq entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

The associated error message is pasted below: -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/entrypoint/Init.py", line 331, in <module>
    serviceRun.setting_all()
  File "/app/entrypoint/Init.py", line 256, in setting_all
    self.do_init_activemq()
  File "/app/entrypoint/Init.py", line 246, in do_init_activemq
    self.replace_all(ACTIVEMQ_CONF + "/log4j.properties", "\$\{activemq\.base\}\/data\/", "/var/log/activemq/")
  File "/app/entrypoint/Init.py", line 27, in replace_all
    f = open(file,'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/activemq/conf.tmp/log4j.properties'
```

It mentions a missing file. Indeed, when I look in the host volumes bound to `/opt/activemq/conf.tmp` and `/opt/activemq/conf` there is nothing in them at all, although one file, `activemq.pid`, does get written to the host volume bound to `/data/activemq`.

Has anyone seen this kind of behaviour and/or perhaps have any suggestions as to where I may be going wrong? Many thanks for reading my question.

Comment: You don't have a volume bound on `/opt/activemq/conf.tmp` accourding to your posted compose file.

Comment: @codestation Thanks, that's a good spot. However, when I added an extra binding for conf.tmp and attempted to redeploy, Init.py throws an error earlier on in its execution:   `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/opt/activemq/conf.tmp'`

Comment: That sounds unrelated to docker. Your container is trying to create that directory and failing if it already exists, so either the directory creation shouldn't fail or the directory shouldn't exist nor be mounted.

Comment: Yes, agreed. The key must be in those mountings. When I go with the ones in my original post, `conf.tmp` doesn't even get created. When I add an extra mounting for it, I get the error in my first comment. Interestingly, when I remove that again and then add a mounting simply to '/opt/activemq', the 'conf.tmp' directory does get created, but the contents remain empty and this error results `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/activemq/bin/linux-x86-64/activemq'`.
It's a bit daunting because I'm new to this, but will keep trying!